# HP DL360 G5 and using 3.5" sata drives OR USB

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, usb, sata

I have a HP DL360 G5 (1x 4core CPU, 4gb Ram, 4x 36gb SAS Hdd's) I am looking for some advice.

This server is just for home use to run some VM's with ESXI 5.1 for my home network and some testing of new OS's etc.

I would like to be able to add some HDD's to the system and I know I can add in some 2.5" SATA drives which I would have to buy BUT I have some 3.5" 2tb drives in caddies which I could remove, could I use a SATA extension cable (ie: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/191096045072?_trksid=p2060778.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) and have the drives outside the case to which I could make a external housing so they are protected

I dont need to use the RAID function

Or is there a USB expansion card I can get to add more USB drives (they only hold simple data like docs and to stream music and video)

is this feasible or am I being to adventurous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably some options for you, but nothing that's HP-supported (short of adding something like an [HP D2600 JBOD enclosure](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/disk-enclosures/product-detail.html?oid=4021628))

[image]

I'd suggest just buying a [NAS or NAS enclosure](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products) to house your disks. You could *try* something that's USB-connected, but the range of devices and controllers supported by ESXi is small. A NAS is going to be safer, considering the age and generation of the server. It could possibly perform better.

Using SATA disks connected to the Smart Array P400 controller inside of your DL380 G5 means that speeds will be downshifted to 1.5Gbps SATA.

Don't do anything silly like using your 2.5" drive bays and SATA extension cables to connect to disks outside of the system...

Comment: hmmmm ok the D2600 is a little out of the question really, I might have to rethink this unless someone else has a good idea or option

Comment: Yes, use a NAS enclosure.

Comment: Would it not be easier to put a 4 port usb pcie card into the DL360 and have 4 USB drives, I know accessing the data would be a bit slower but it is not all mission critical and I could run the VM's off the internal sas drives already there ?

Comment: "*You could try something that's USB-connected, but the range of devices and controllers supported by ESXi is small.*" So, maybe? But VMware ESXi is not really built around supporting consumer equipment. There's a slight chance it could work, but USB datastores are not supported.

Comment: I would be using the USB HDD's as passthroughs so the VM OS is directly accessing them for the music, films, docs etc

the 4 internal SAS drives should be enough room to hold my VM's

Comment: @AdamMannPro As it's for labbing, just use a freenas appliance with the hdd in it. That support iscsi connection.